# can't generate zip-with-dependencies.zip file on target folder(maven)

Tags: java, maven, cucumber, testng, appium

i am trying to generate the zip file in the target folder but i can't. maven build success when i run the following command

```
mvn clean package -DskipTests=true
```

and jar file & tests.jar files also was generated
but didn’t generate zip-with-dependencies.zip file only jars files. what is wrong here?

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project 
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Nana</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- API, java.xml.bind module -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Runtime, com.sun.xml.bind module -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vimalselvam</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-extentsreport</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.javafaker/javafaker -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.javafaker</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafaker</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/uk.ac.gate.plugins/lang-arabic -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>uk.ac.gate.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>lang-arabic</artifactId>
            <version>8.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.5.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20190722</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>

    <profiles>

        <profile>
            <id>full</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
                <property>
                    <name>environment</name>
                    <value>regression</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <testNGSuite>testng.xml</testNGSuite>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>


    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.6</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>test-jar</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>


                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.10</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/dependency-jars/</outputDirectory>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.4</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>single</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <finalName>zip-with-dependencies</finalName>
                                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                                <descriptors>
                                    <descriptor>src/main/java/assembly/zip.xml</descriptor>
                                </descriptors>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.7</source>
                        <target>1.7</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.1</version>
                    <configuration>


                        <source>8</source>
                        <target>8</target>

                    </configuration>



                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <suiteXmlFiles>
                            <!--suiteXmlFile>${testNGSuite}</suiteXmlFile-->
                        </suiteXmlFiles>
                    </configuration>

                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

zip.xml:

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.0.xsd">
    <id>zip</id>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
            <outputDirectory>./</outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>*.jar</include>
            </includes>
        </fileSet>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
            <outputDirectory>./</outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>/dependency-jars/</include>
            </includes>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

Logs:

```
omyma@ubuntu:~/shopper-automation$ mvn clean install -DskipTests=true
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1 (file:/usr/share/maven/lib/guice.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.example:Nana:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.pluginManagement.plugins.plugin.(groupId:artifactId)' must be unique but found duplicate declaration of plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin @ line 221, column 25
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --------------------------< org.example:Nana >--------------------------
[INFO] Building Nana 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ Nana ---
[INFO] Deleting /home/omyma/shopper-automation/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ Nana ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/omyma/shopper-automation/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ Nana ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ Nana ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/omyma/shopper-automation/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ Nana ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 11 source files to /home/omyma/shopper-automation/target/test-classes
[INFO] /home/omyma/shopper-automation/src/test/java/step_definition/MyStepdefs.java: /home/omyma/shopper-automation/src/test/java/step_definition/MyStepdefs.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
[INFO] /home/omyma/shopper-automation/src/test/java/step_definition/MyStepdefs.java: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5:test (default-test) @ Nana ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.6:jar (default-jar) @ Nana ---
[WARNING] JAR will be empty - no content was marked for inclusion!
[INFO] Building jar: /home/omyma/shopper-automation/target/Nana-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.6:test-jar (default) @ Nana ---
[INFO] Building jar: /home/omyma/shopper-automation/target/Nana-1.0-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ Nana ---
[INFO] Installing /home/omyma/shopper-automation/target/Nana-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to /home/omyma/.m2/repository/org/example/Nana/1.0-SNAPSHOT/Nana-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing /home/omyma/shopper-automation/pom.xml to /home/omyma/.m2/repository/org/example/Nana/1.0-SNAPSHOT/Nana-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] Installing /home/omyma/shopper-automation/target/Nana-1.0-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar to /home/omyma/.m2/repository/org/example/Nana/1.0-SNAPSHOT/Nana-1.0-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.850 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-11-14T05:49:15-08:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put the declarations into `<pluginManagement>`. To execute them you need to move them to the `<plugins>` section.

BTW: You defined the Java version at three locations in the POM which is not really sensible.